# What is the name for someone who never stays in one place?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Im trying to name a spacecraft for a novel, and am looking for the term for someone (or a group of someones) who never settles in one place, and it always traveling and exploring, something that might fit a spacecraft built for exploring and prospecting.

Personally I was considering "Sojourner", for someone who only stays a short while at a given place, as the ship which carries the name is, or was, exploring the solar system and only stopping at ports of call for a short while, just to head out into the great empty.

I've done some research, but I'm looking for something with a positive connotation, as opposed to one which implies that the ship in question is dilapidated, in poor condition, or lacking class, as the ship is (in universe) the flagship of a well-off mining fleet. (Or at least it was when it was built and in service, having gone missing in its travel without explanation, and only found in the present day, as an anomaly.)

Think 'The Expanse' novels, if you need context for the kind of universe I'm talking about.

Comment: [Sojourner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sojourner_(rover)) has some NASA mileage.

Comment: A rolling stone? Which gathers no moss, etc.. already probably too much in use, if anything.

Comment: @KillingTime I know, which is why I'm still looking. Don't feel like ripping them off.

Comment: Straight from an online thesaurus: *nomad, vagabond, adventurer, beachcomber, bum, drifter, explorer, floater, gadabout, gypsy, itinerant, pilgrim, rambler, ranger, roamer, straggler, stray, stroller, traveler/traveller, vagrant, voyager, gallivanter, globetrotter, meanderer, etc.*

Comment: You should probably ask Elon Musk :)

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Nasa already came up with ***Voyager*** for just this context, half a century ago.

Comment: *Peripatetic* is a great word.

Comment: I can see why this is in the close queue, as it is asking for a name, which is off-topic. On the other hand, essentially, you're looking for a synonym to a word you have described, and you limit the potential answers by adding a requirement. VTLO.

Comment: **roamer** is an option for someone who likes to move around and travel, especially without a clear idea of what they want to do (
*He's a bit of a roamer, so he could be anywhere in the country*) or for 
someone who moves from one country to another to live and work (*Roamers move abroad with just a couple of suitcases on a regular basis in search of professional or personal opportunities*).

Comment: **pathfinder** (*a person who finds or makes a path, way, route, etc., especially through a previously unexplored or untraveled wilderness*) has perhaps the expected positive connotation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestions previously offered in both answers and comments, you could use ***peripatetic***, [both as an adjective and as a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peripatetic) (link is to Merriam-Webster).

(as an adjective:)

> 1 a: of, relating to, or given to walking
> b: moving or traveling from place to place : ITINERANT

(as a noun:)

> 1: PEDESTRIAN, ITINERANT

Answer (score 0):

*Nomad* or *vagabond* could work, though I think that the second one is slightly better. Though in the past it may have been used negatively, it has a nice feel to it.

> **nomad:** a person who does not stay long in the same place; a wanderer ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=nomad%20define))

> **vagabond**, *noun*: a person who wanders from place to place without a fixed home : one leading a vagabond life
>
> **vagabond**, *adj.*:
> moving from place to place without a fixed home : WANDERING
> of, relating to, or characteristic of a wanderer
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vagabond))

There are lots of other synonyms for this, like *wanderer, journeyer, rover, voyager, and wayfarer.*

Comment: I think something like wanderer fits the build better, as (I probably should have specified) I am looking for a name which doesn't carry the connotation of someone who travels because they have to, or because they cant find a home. More like someone who travels because they want to see the world and they have the resources to do so, as it was a flagship when it was in service.

Comment: *Vagabond* is archaic, so it's never lost the negative connotation it had when it was in more common use.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, do an ngram search for *vagabond*, it seems to be regaining popularity over the past couple decades. Based on the first search hits it's mostly used for titles rather than in the body of books, but labeling it "archaic" is probably premature.

Answer (score 0):

[Globetrotter](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/globetrotter) might work

> a habitual worldwide traveller, esp a tourist or businessperson
>
> a person who travels regularly or frequently to countries all over the world

TFD defines the verb [globetrot](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/globetrotter) as

> To travel often and widely, especially for sightseeing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [wanderer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wanderer):

> One who wanders, who travels aimlessly.

It also brings to mind 'wanderlust' (and a personal favourite word because of [the iconic romanticist painting by Caspar David Friedrich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanderer_above_the_Sea_of_Fog) bearing the word in its title, both in the German and the English version).